# Amazon S3 and swfaddress

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, amazon-s3, swfobject, swfaddress

I recently migrated a large AS3 site (lots of swfs, lots of flvs) to Amazon S3.  Pretty much everything but HTML and JS files is being stored/served from Amazon, and it's working well.  The only problem I'm having is that I built the site using [SWFaddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) (actually, via the [Gaia framework](http://www.gaiaflashframework.com/index.php?www) which uses SWFaddress), and for some reason, SWFaddress is no longer updating the address bar correctly as users navigate from page to page.  In other words, the URL persistently remains http://www.mysite.com, not http://www.mysite.com/#/section as would be the case were SWFaddress functioning correctly (and as it was functioning prior to the migration).

Stranger yet, if I go to (e.g.) http://www.mysite.com/#/section directly, the deeplinking functions as you'd expect--I arrive directly at the correct section.  However, navigating away from that section doesn't have any effect on the address bar, despite the fact that it should be dynamically updated.

I've got a crossdomain.xml file set up on the site that allows access from all domains, so that's not the issue, and I don't know what else might be.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I integrated S3 by putting pretty much the entire site in an S3 bucket and then just changing the initial swfobject embed to point to the S3 instance of main.swf, passing in the S3 path as the "base" param to the embedded swf so that all dynamically loaded assets and swfs would also be sourced from s3.  Dunno if that's related to the troubles I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Cross Site Scripting problem, you cannot call javascript methods from one domain to another basically. You can alternatively setup a server-side proxy script on your domain to trick the browser (I haven't tried .htaccess / urlrewriting but might be more elegant if it works).

Comment: Theo--any idea how I might go about solving this problem?  I'm still having it and I can't figure it out, despite the fact that my s3 share is at http://media.mydomain.com and the site is served from mydomain.com.  I wouldn't think there'd be a security issue here, but apparently something's still not right...