# swfaddress setValue() with amazon s3 bucket

Tags: actionscript-3, amazon-s3, flex4.6, swfaddress

For my flex apps deeplinking, I use swfaddress 2.4. It works before but now problem occurred when I migrate my flex apps to be hosted on Amazon S3 bucket.

I have done this:

- policy file set on each domain that the app will access to load assets/data
- `allowScriptAccess` is set to `always`
- the policy files are loaded (via `loadPolicyFile`) when the apps is initiated
- `allowDomain` (and `allowInsecureDomain`) also been set

The problem:

- when calling SWFAddress.setValue(), the address on browser address bar is never been changed. When debug, the `_value` in swfaddress.js is correctly holding the value that been passed
- this breaks browser history (back button in broswer and the apps can't be used)
- manually enter a query into adddress bar throws this error:

  ```
  Uncaught Error: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error.
  ```

  and

  ```
  Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject
  ```

  which is from the function `_swfChange` in line: `obj[setter](value);` where `setter`   is the `setSWFAddressValue` callbacks in SWFAddress.as. So, I had even made the SWFAddress.as to execute `_initialize` function where it adds the callbacks

  - whe i put the try..catch at the problematic line, it goes into the infamous infinite-loop swfaddress problem. Adding a fix to that like recommended, now the apps didn't change the view state

Thanks in advance.

//btw, it's similar to this unsolved probleem: [Amazon S3 and swfaddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428256/amazon-s3-and-swfaddress)

Comment: adding try..catch in `_setValue` solved the app hanged problem..
but the back function and manually edit the query in adress bar will not change the app view state(as the `_swfChange` is now not notify the app)...

using BrowserManager will throw the above error too...
looks like js can't communicate with app but the app can communicate with js

Comment: btw, try..catch is showing nothing when i log the error message in the catch statement to console log